# Typescript cannot find module 'worker_threads'

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-worker-threads

I am trying to use node.js 'worker_threads' library with Node v14.15.1 and getting this error

```
Cannot find module 'worker_threads' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

```
tsc 

src/api/services/email.service.ts:1:62 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'worker_threads'.

1 import { Worker, isMainThread, parentPort, workerData } from 'worker_threads';
                                                              

Found 1 error.
```

my code -

```
import { Worker, isMainThread, parentPort, workerData } from 'worker_threads';
```

worker threads got stable after node 11. So it should work.
What am i doing wrong ?

PS - I ran same code with JS and it worked fine so i don't think its Node.js issue. Other core libraries like fs are also working fine. Do I need any additional config for TS ?

Comment: `npm install @types/node` or the equivalent command for your package manager of choice.

Comment: Thanks but already done that and other core libraries like 'fs' are working fine. Its just with this library

Comment: Verify that the version of the @types package is correct

Comment: @AluanHaddad thanks for your help.
I don't remember why, but I was having very old version of @types/node and ts-node.
After updating it worked great.
Thanks again!

Comment: @RohanGulati I have exactly the same problem, what versions of @types/node and ts-node did you update to? Would be helpful if you could specify the steps as an answer or in comments.

Comment: @ChrisOdney thanks for reminding. I have added answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue was that I was using quite old versions. After updating, the issue was resolved.
If someone faces same issue, update these versions in your package.json -
I have updated to

- "@types/node": "14.14.14"
- "ts-node": "9.1.1"

Also make sure Nodejs version is 12 LTS or above to have stable 'worker-thread' support.

Comment: It doesn't help for "ts-node": "^9.1.1" and "@types/node": "^14.14.37".

Comment: @EugeneZalivadnyi This is well tested with these versions. What problem are you facing ? May be I can help

Answer (score 2):

In my case, this problem happened in my **Angular** project after `npm audit fix --force`

So after few attempts here's what I did:

- updating node with `sudo n stable` (you should install Node’s version manager first)

---

- `ng update`

This command will give you few recommendations in a column named **Command to update** run each separately and make sure it worked correctly.

Then I run `ng serve` and everything got back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error on ubuntu. I recently installed node on my new machine. I had been on Windows before. I realized that I was using a much older version of node (v10 or similar).

After upgrading the node version to the latest v16.13.1, I was able to resolve the error. I also had to delete the node_modules folder and package-lock.json file. I took Rohan's suggestion above and followed the instructions provided here:

https://github.com/enable3d/enable3d/issues/231

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).